# Multi-step form using GET requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have the unusual requirement of a multi-step form through GET requests.  So, instead of POSTing the forms, we're using GET requests to pass new parameters to the query.  So, the basic idea is that there's a treatment, and a date passed to the query.  A three-step form if you will.

1. Show available treatments, pick one
2. Show available dates (there's business logic in the background that figures these out)
3. Pick a time

The URL will go through the following states

1. site.com/bookings/new
2. site.com/bookings/new/[id|name_of_treatment] (by this, I mean it could either by the ID field or the name of the the treatment)
3. site.com/bookings/new/[id|name_of_treatment]/2010-12-12/

So, my route looks like this:

```
map.connect 'bookings/new/:massage_type/:date', :controller => :bookings, :action => :new
```

massage_type is synonymous with the treatment_id.

So my form_tag looks like this:

```
<% form_tag( {:action => "new"}, :method => "get" ) do %>
```

The problem I'm having is that I want it to just give me back the URL site.com/bookings/new/[id|name_of_treatment]/ but instead it gives back the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/bookings/new?massage_type[treatment_id]=1&commit=actionnew
```

I don't suppose anyone knows?

Comment: Off topic: Are the perks good when coding the website for a massage parlor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms that use `GET` are adding the input values as query parameters. There's no way to make the form post to a different URL, where the input values are part of the URL instead - it's just not supported by the HTML standard.

You could use URL rewrite to remap the incoming URLs of this type to the one you want, however that's not really a good solution, because this would result in a second request.

However, what I don't understand is why does the form need to do `GET` to that specific URL. Is it a requirement that these URLs can be constructed by the user manually, instead of using the form?

If there is no such requirement, I would advise to use standard `POST` form to `http://localhost:3000/bookings/new` and modify the form in the response based on the parameters in the `POST` body, as necessary.

Better yet, write some Ajax that would update the form according to the user's choice, without making a full form submit, until the user has finished all the choices.

Comment: It's a three-step form basically, but you should be able to jump to any step, because another page offers the opportunity to go straight to a second step for example.

Comment: The other page can get you to the right state by `POST`ing the right parameters. The only reason you would need that URL format is if you want to enable the user to construct it by hand (as I mentioned it already).

Comment: Well, it _would_ be possible to POST from the other pages I guess.  I don't like multi-step forms at all really, but we wanted a solution that is accessible using progressive enhancement so we don't rely on javascript entirely.  We basically start from the ground up.  I guess I can POST it, and then from the other pages, I could create loads of forms that POST the necessary variables

Comment: Furthermore, I wanted the URL to reflect where you were in the process.

Comment: Why? What goal would this serve? :-) But sure, you can do that, however, as I said, the HTML spec is clear about how the URL is formed when sending a form (through either `GET` or `POST`). Though, you could execute Javascript on the form submit, that would redirect the browser to the URL you want using the input fields of the form.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the result of a `GET` request will have a query string (`?param1=value1&param2=value2&...`) in its URL.  To get rid of those, you'll have to either start using `POST` or immediately redirect to the desired URL upon receiving a `GET` request.

I rather like the redirect approach because it doesn't show that confusing/annoying message about resubmitting POST data when the user refreshes their browser.

Comment: One option I was thinking of was instant redirection, which is perfectly viable I guess